# Wordpress не изменяет less

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap, wordpress

Создаю на денвере проект Wordpress с bootstrap less. Подключаю, и вроде все нормально. Но при попытке изменить что либо в less файлах bootstrap ничего не меняется, то есть страница остается со стандартными стилями bootstrap. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле проблема с Less файлами возникает из за кэширования Wordpress. Поэтому для того, чтобы отменить его, нужно использовать следующий трюк:

```
  <link type="text/css" href="<?php echo $themedir ?>/css/style.less?t=<?php echo time() ?>" rel="stylesheet/less" />
```

то есть мы добавляем несуществующий get параметр t к имени нашего файла вот этой частью строки ?t=<?php echo time() ?>, заставляя тем самым вордпресc подгружать его заново каждый раз.